# How I can use result with another text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am setting coupons things in my store but I want to do something with my JavaScript alter and I have no idea how to do it.

```
success: function (result) {
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'center',
        type: 'success',
        title: "Coupon check",
        text: (result),
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
    })
}
```

This is my script function with result and my question is how I can do like this:

> Your coupon for `(result)` was successfully added!

As I do not know how I can use `(result)` in `"` or `'`.

Comment: Not sure I am following but you may be looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
            text: "Your coupon for " + result + " was successfully added!",
```

Comment: Awesome ! it help me thanks alot for your quick help.

Comment: This is something even a beginning programmer should know how to do. What was your confusion?

Comment: Well I just beginning  to do something like this and when I check the docs for information about it I did not find it  or I have miss it. So that mean I have to read and learning more..